# Do I need to clear server side intervals?

Tags: node.js, websocket, multiplayer

I have a server side function to check if a player is idle

```
socket.idle = 0;
socket.cached = {};
socket.checkIdle = function(){
   socket.idle++;
   console.log(socket.idle);
   if(socket.cached.x != players[id].x || socket.cached.y != players[id].y){
      socket.idle=0;
   }
   socket.cached = players[id];
   if(socket.idle>12){
      socket.disconnect();
   }
}

socket.interval = setInterval(socket.checkIdle,1000);
```

I've noticed that even after the player gets booted/disconnected for being too long. The server still console log the socket.idle for it.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Also should I then clear the interval for when the player disconnects?

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   clearInterval(socket.interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't leave a `setInterval()` running for a player that is no longer connected.  Your server will just have more and more of these running, wasting CPU cycles and possibly impacting your server's responsiveness or scalability.

> I've noticed that even after the player gets booted/disconnected for being too long. The server still console log the socket.idle for it.

Yeah, that's because the interval is still running and, in fact, it even keeps the socket object from getting garbage collected.  All of that is bad.

> Also should I then clear the interval for when the player disconnects?

Yes, when a socket disconnects, you must clear the interval timer associated with that socket.

> Am I going about this the wrong way?

If you keep with the architecture of a polling interval timer for each separate socket, then this is the right way to clear the timer when the socket disconnects.

But, I would think that maybe you could come up with another design that doesn't need to regularly "poll" for idle at all.  It appears you want to have a 12 second timeout such that if the player hasn't moved within 12 seconds, then you disconnect the user.  There's really no reason to check for this every second.  You could just set a single timer with `setTimeout()` for 12 seconds from when the user connects and then each time you get notified of player movement (which your server must already being notified about since you're referencing it in `players[id].x` and `players[id].y`), you just clear the old timer and set a new one.  When the timer fires, you must have gone 12 seconds without motion and you can then disconnect.  This would be more typically how a timeout-type timer would work.